# convert stream to zip file

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I have made a WCF web service that streams a 200 mb zip file. Can some one please advise me on how i can read this stream at my client and then give option to the user to download that

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide more details about the "client" part of the application?

Comment: thanks for the reply. The service and client is build in .net 2008.

I have created a proxy and i am able to call my method that returns stream object, but how do i read that stream and give option the user to download it.

Service1Client obj = new Service1Client();
            string[] IDs= new string[]{};
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(obj.GetCoverScan(IDs));

THis file i am streaming is already a zip file

Answer (score 1):

If your client is an asp.net site, why not just a simple ashx handler? Set the mime type application/x-zip, and set the ResponseStream of the handler to the zip file stream.

Comment: thanks for the reply,  Well i have a simple ashx handler that calls my WCF service. but i am stuglling to read the stream. Can you please provide me some code

Comment: Actually, you want a binary reader so you can read byte arrays.

Comment: but if i read it into a byte array then it i don't think i can get the complete benifit of streaming. Please advise

Comment: You read it in chunks, inside a while loop. Are you offerinf for download through an ashx handler or other method?

Comment: i am doing it in a ashx handler

Comment: I don't think there is a more effecient way than reading chunks of the file in a while loop. and doing context.Response.Write(). Check out the HttpRespons class though. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhy78ycf.aspx